# Shiny app produces error: "arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1"

Tags: r, shiny, r-caret, caret, glmnet

I am trying to create an R Shiny app that calculates a score using ridge regression and then uses that in a random forest model. I saved both models as RDS and kept them in the same folder where the app.R is.

Then I read the models and data of predicted probabilities and define some functions:

```
    # Reading data
    phats <- read.csv("Predicted_probabilities_training.csv")
    phats_graph <- phats %>% mutate(`PTD Event Status` = ifelse(Observed_Event=="PTD", "PTD Event", "No PTD Event"))
    phats_event <- phats[phats$Observed_Event=="PTD",]
    phats_nonevent <- phats[phats$Observed_Event=="No_PTD",]
            
    # load the models
    ridge_model <- readRDS("ridge_model.rds")
    final_model <- readRDS("final_model.rds")

        # Defining some functions
matrix.for.ILS.function <- function(input){
  return(data.matrix(data.frame(input$MIP_1a,
               input$MIP_3a,
               input$RANTES,
               input$sIL_6R,
               input$ITAC,
               input$IL_21,
               input$Fractalkine,
               input$TNF_a,
               input$IL_1b,
               input$IL_7,
               input$IL_10,
               input$GM_CSF,
               input$MIP_1b)))
}

ILS.function <- function(input){
  ILS.ridge = as.numeric(predict(ridge_model, matrix.for.ILS.function(input), s = 0.7414409, type="link"))
  return(ILS.ridge)
}

test.data.function <- function(input){
  test.data = data.frame(Age=input$Age,
                  Gender=input$Gender,
                  GCS_Bestin24=input$GCS_Bestin24,
                  Premorbid_depression=input$Premorbid_depression,
                  Antidep_first6m=input$Antidep_first6m)
  return(cbind(test.data, ILS.ridge=ILS.function(input)))
}

pred_prob_func <- function(input){
  pred_prob = predict(final_model, test.data.function(input), type="prob")[,"PTD"]
  classification <- ifelse(pred_prob >= input$thresholdslider, "PTD Event", "No Event")
  return(list(pred_prob=pred_prob, classification=classification))
}
```

Then after writing the UI and server codes, I try to produce a graph, but it shows me the error: "arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1". I tested that `pred_prob_func` produces that error. Although when I tried to create a list called `input` by just creating a list of random values for the variables and try to see if `pred_prob_func(input)` produces a value, it actually produces a value. But when I try to run the app, the graph doesn't show up and gives me this error. I'm using the following codes in the server section to produce the graph.

```
  output$int_plot <- renderPlotly({

    phats_graph$`Total Percentile` <- unlist(t(sapply(phats_graph$Phat, function(x) quantile_fun(value=x)))[,1])
    phats_graph$`PTD Percentile` <- unlist(t(sapply(phats_graph$Phat, function(x) quantile_fun(value=x)))[,2])
    phats_graph$`No PTD Percentile` <- unlist(t(sapply(phats_graph$Phat, function(x) quantile_fun(value=x)))[,3])

    int_plot <- ggplot(phats_graph, aes(ptd_per=`No PTD Percentile`)) + geom_density(aes(x=Phat, fill = `PTD Event Status`), alpha=0.5) +
      geom_vline(xintercept = input$thresholdslider, linetype = 'dashed') +
      geom_vline(xintercept = pred_prob_func(input)$pred_prob) +
      xlab('Threshold Percentage') + ylab('Density') +
      theme_minimal() + scale_fill_manual(values=c("#5D3A9B", "#E66100"), name="")


    ggplotly(int_plot, tooltip=c("x", "ptd_per"))

  })
```

Is there a problem with how I define the functions?

**Edits:**

All files (data, RDS models) and the app can be found in this [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1UEJCzfPXKQgqr1d6X3j_cQ_TJq3hyrKs?usp=sharing) for testing.

I have tested the functions using the following example inputs (which produced results when I used this as an argument in the functions, but shows this error when I try to run the app):

```
input=list(Age=20, Gender=1, GCS_Bestin24=4, Premorbid_depression=0, Antidep_first6m=0,
           MIP_1a=1,
           MIP_3a=1,
           RANTES=1,
           sIL_6R=1,
           ITAC=1,
           IL_21=1,
           Fractalkine=1,
           TNF_a=1,
           IL_1b=1,
           IL_7=1,
           IL_10=1,
           GM_CSF=1,
           MIP_1b=1,
           thresholdslider=0.5)
```

Comment: Let me know if I can give more info and I can edit the question.

Comment: Have you tried to identify wher exactly the errors happens ? I think it might be in the `cbind` function in `test.data.function`. You should add some `print(input$Age)` etc ... in this function to make sure your inputs do have values.

Comment: @gdevaux I have tested the functions using the inputs now I have in my edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The orignial error is occuring because you are not asking for the same `input$id` as the `id` you assign in `textInput`.

```
textInput("MIPa", label = HTML("MIP-1\\(\\alpha\\)") ##used in ui

input$MIP_1a ##used in server.
```

I think there is a problem with shiny using the `input` variable.

By creating a list of the inputs as `input_list` and changing the places where you call `input` by itself to `input()` it seems to work.

I also needed to remove the `test.data.function(input)` right after the `test.data.function()` function was created in order to get the app to run.

```
    input_list <- reactive({
    input_list <- list( Age=as.numeric(input$Age),
                Gender=ifelse(input$Gender == "Female", 1, 0), 
                GCS_Bestin24=as.numeric(input$GCS_Bestin24),
             Premorbid_depression=as.numeric(input$Premorbid_depression),
                Antidep_first6m=as.numeric(input$Antidep_first6m),
                MIP_1a = as.numeric(input$MIPa),
                MIP_3a = as.numeric(input$MIP_3a),
                RANTES = as.numeric(input$RANTES),
                sIL_6R = as.numeric(input$sIL_6R),
                ITAC = as.numeric(input$ITAC),
                IL_21 = as.numeric(input$IL_21),
                Fractalkine = as.numeric(input$Fractalkine),
                TNF_a = as.numeric(input$TNF_a),
                IL_1b = as.numeric(input$ILb),
                IL_7 = as.numeric(input$IL_7),
                IL_10 = as.numeric(input$IL0),
                GM_CSF = as.numeric(input$GM_CSF),
                MIP_1b = as.numeric(input$MIPb))
    input_list
  })
```

```
##input changed to input_list()
##this needs to be done for each instance where input is used on its own.
geom_vline(xintercept = pred_prob_func(input_list())$pred_prob)
```

To remove the final error message you need to change the `renderPlotly()` to `renderUI()` and include a check for `NA` values in the `input_list`.

The `plotlyOutput` also needs to be changed to `uiOutput()` in the `ui` section.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
                uiOutput('int_plot') #changed from plotlyOutput('int_plot')
               )

server <- (
output$int_plot <- renderUI({
    if(anyNA(input_list())){
     helpText("Input User data")
    }else{
      phats_graph$`Total Percentile` <- unlist(t(sapply(phats_graph$Phat, function(x) quantile_fun(value=x)))[,1])
      phats_graph$`PTD Percentile` <- unlist(t(sapply(phats_graph$Phat, function(x) quantile_fun(value=x)))[,2])
      phats_graph$`No PTD Percentile` <- unlist(t(sapply(phats_graph$Phat, function(x) quantile_fun(value=x)))[,3])
      
      
      
      int_plot <- ggplot(phats_graph, aes(ptd_per=`No PTD Percentile`)) + geom_density(aes(x=Phat, fill = `PTD Event Status`), alpha=0.5) +
        geom_vline(xintercept = input$thresholdslider, linetype = 'dashed') +
        geom_vline(xintercept = pred_prob_func(input_list())$pred_prob) +
        xlab('Threshold Percentage') + ylab('Density') +
        theme_minimal() + scale_fill_manual(values=c("#5D3A9B", "#E66100"), name="")
      
      
      renderPlotly( ggplotly(int_plot, tooltip=c("x", "ptd_per")))
    }


  })
)
```

When age is 10 and all values are 1 (no idea what these should be) this is the output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I edited my codes but still get an error saying "variables ‘Age’, ‘Gender’, ‘Premorbid_depression’, ‘Antidep_first6m’ were specified with different types from the fit". I checked that in the original data on which I ran the random forest models to get the "final_model.RDS", all variables were integers (some of them were binary (0/1). How should I fix it to produce the graph? Did the app produce the graph when you tried it?

Comment: I have updated the `input_list` with a version that works when data is provided. If you change each of the `input$variable` to `numeric` with `as.numeric()` it will return a correct result. You will need to check how the `Gender` variable needs to be assigned to a numeric value (e.g. `Female=1`), and it only produces a graph if there is data provided. Otherwise there is an `Error: User interrupt or internal error.` message.

Comment: Thank you so much! You are awesome! Is there a way to suppress this ``Error: User interrupt or internal error`` or maybe show a message asking to enter values?

Comment: I have updated the answer to add a message instead of an error message. You can make this whatever you want (e.g. a table displaying the current patient values).

Comment: it works fine when I run the app locally. But it shows me an error "An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification." when I deploy it to the server. I'm not sure why that would happen. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You'll need a more specific error message than that. If you check the log file what is it saying?